# Is there something invalidating my code from being accepted as an XML file?

Tags: html, xml, templates, xslt

Getting an error that this body of code isn't valid as part of an XSL file. That's the only feedback that this document system gives me. This is part of a larger document but I thought I would try isolating the issue to see if it's in the first half of the document

```
<xsl:template match="ws:Worker_Sync">
    <File etv:separator="&#xd;&#xa;">
        <Header etv:separator=";">
            <HeaderItem1>EEID</HeaderItem1>
            <HeaderItem2>FirstNAME</HeaderItem2>
            <HeaderItem3>LastNAME</HeaderItem3>
            <HeaderItem4>INTNAME</HeaderItem4>
            <HeaderItem5>OHDATE</HeaderItem5>
            <HeaderItem6>SALARY</HeaderItem6>
        </Header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ws:Worker"/>
        <Footer>
            <WorkerCount etv:number="totalCount">
            </WorkerCount>
            <DateTimeviaXpath>
                <etv:class etv:name="FormatDates" etv:dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <etv:class etv:name="FormatTime" etv:timeFormat="HH-mm-ss"
                <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime"/>
            </DateTimeviaXpath>
        </Footer>
    </File>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: There is something missing in the middle, possibly a `>` and `</etv:class>` - as, well, highlighted by the syntax highlighting. If that is not your actual error, please show a complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

This `etv:class` element

```
<etv:class etv:name="FormatTime" etv:timeFormat="HH-mm-ss"
```

needs to be

```
<etv:class etv:name="FormatTime" etv:timeFormat="HH-mm-ss"/>
```